# t-test, chi-squared test or Poisson test?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution

I have to compare the survival proportion between two treatments. Because of some limitations, I can only take a sample of $n_{1}=5$ animals from treatment 1, and $n_{2}=50$ animals from treatment 2. Both samples come from the same batch so that these two samples can be considered as paired. The survival proportion of sample 1 is then compared with the survival of sample 2. Note that the $5$ animals in treatment 1 are considered as one replicate, and the same is for the 50 animals from treatment 2. So that the experimental unit is 5/50 animals, rather than individual animal.

If $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ are both large, the differences between proportions can be considered as a continuous variable. Therefore, I could conduct the experiment N times, and apply a paired t-test to compare the average proportions between the two populations.

However, due to a small number of sample $n_{1}=5$ for treatment 1, the survival proportion for treatment 1 is discrete: $0/5, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 5/5$, which means it will be a problem for t-test.

On the other hand, if I apply chi-squared test or test for Poisson distributions, the experimental units are defined as individual animals, which is not the same as this case.

Can someone give some advice about how to compare the average proportion in this case?

To add some explanation about this experiment: This is a typical ecological experiment, where the treatments are different-sized boxes making two different living environments. So basically we are testing the living environment, and the animals are living as a community. Imagine if we compare people's quality of life under two different community environments, people's feelings indeed are influenced by one another. If one individual feels stressed by the environment, people living together with him will be influenced.

Comment: $0/5$ is a possible survival proportion, also.

Comment: I'm really not sure why you don't want to use Fisher's exact test ($\chi^2$ for small sample size).

Comment: prop.test() in R should do exactly what you want: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/prop.test.html

Comment: @ Ellis Valentiner, because if I use Fisher's exact test, I would consider each individual animal as an independent replicate. In my case, animals behave as a group (they are not independent), thus the survival can only be estimated by group and the independent experimental unit is a group of animals. To be specific, my treatments are two different-sized boxes,. Therefore, in order to keep a constant living density within the two boxes, I ended up with $n_{1}=5$ and $n_{2}=10$

Comment: @talischen if the animals in a group don't survive or die all together, what is the sense in which they aren't independent. Are you saying that within a group (of 5 or 50) their chances of death are related?

Comment: @Glen_b. Sorry that I didnt explain the experiment very well. This is a typical ecological experiment, where the treatments are different sized boxes making two different living environment. So basically we are testing the living environment, and the animals are living as a community. Imagine if we compare people's quality of life under two different community environment, people's feelings indeed are influenced by one another. If one individual feel stressed by the environment, people living toegther with him will be influenced.

Comment: This kind of experiment is different than breeding several animals in the cage, while the treatment is a drug and animals behaves independently to the drug.

Comment: Thanks for editing that into your question. One approach would be to use a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM), treating the association between the groups as a random effect.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. GLMM is exactly the answer that I want. Would you mind editing it as answer, instead of comment?

Comment: Sure, but to be acceptable as an answer it needs to give more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM), treating the association between the groups as a random effect.

In this case, it seems to me like an appropriate starting place would be a binomial model, with a logit link, and a simple scalar random effect. It's not clear to me from the description what the form of the fixed effect might be.